# Getting the subset for a quantmod chartSeries after a call to zooom

Tags: r, quantmod

After a call to the zooom function (which allows the user to interactively change the zoom of the chart by clicking on the leftmost and rightmost bounds for the zoom), is it possible to get the resulting subset displayed?

The reasons I want this:

1. To set an appropriate yrange for my chart based on the custom TAs that I've added that would otherwise not be visible, because the automatic yrange is based only the timeseries passed to the original call to chartSeries
2. To implement functions to pan the chart left and right

Workarounds for these 2 goals that don't involve getting the current subset would also be helpful. Currently the only option I can think of is to avoid the use of the interactive zooom function and just use chartZoom.

Comment: I've discovered that the chartSeries returns an object that has attributes on it that specify various details about the chart, including the attribute xrange that has indicies into the timeseries. However the attributes on the original object returned by chartSeries do not seem to be modified when I call zooom, and zooom doesn't return anything.

Comment: Sorry for the edit bump, I am now aware there really is a function with the spelling [`zooom`](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=zooom&type=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to know is why `zoomChart()` returns the values you want, but `zooom()` doesn't.

`zoomChart()` does because it calls the function `reChart()`, which ends with the line `invisible(chob)`. (`chob` is the name of the object you're after.)

`zooom()` doesn't do this. It calls `zoomChart()`, but it doesn't arrange to pass `chob` out of the environment within which `zoomChart()` is being evaluated. You can do that, though, by creating a modified version of `zooom()`

I did this by first dumping `zooom` to a file and then creating an edited function called `zooom2`:

```
require(quantmod)
dump("zooom", file="zooom2.R")
```

The three edits I made were:

1. Replace calls to `get.chob()` with calls to `quantmod:::get.chob()`.  This is needed because, unlike `zooom`, `zooom2` does not have `namespace:quantmod` as its enclosing environment.
2. Assign the output of `zoomChart()` to the object `chob`.
3. Return `chob` to the calling environment by ending the function with `invisible(chob)`.

Here's the modified function:

```
zooom2 <-
function (n = 1, eps = 2) 
{
for (i in 1:n) {
    cat("select left and right extremes by clicking the chart\n")
    points <- locator(2)
    if (abs(diff(points$x)) < eps) {
    zoomChart()
    }
    else {
    usr <- par("usr")
    xdata <- quantmod:::get.chob()[[2]]@xdata
    xsubset <- quantmod:::get.chob()[[2]]@xsubset
    sq <- floor(seq(usr[1], usr[2], 1))
    st <- which(floor(points$x[1]) == sq)/length(sq) * 
        NROW(xdata[xsubset])
    en <- which(floor(points$x[2]) == sq)/length(sq) * 
        NROW(xdata[xsubset])
    sorted <- sort(c(st, en))
    st <- sorted[1]
    en <- sorted[2] * 1.05
    chob <- zoomChart(paste(index(xdata[xsubset])[max(1, floor(st), 
        na.rm = TRUE)], index(xdata[xsubset])[min(ceiling(en), 
        NROW(xdata[xsubset]), na.rm = TRUE)], sep = "::"))
    }
}
cat("done\n")
invisible(chob)

}
```

You can source or paste the function back into your R session, and then use it like this (for example):

```
  data(sample_matrix)
  chartSeries(sample_matrix)
  d <- zooom2()
  # Click to interactively zoom in

  # extract the data visible in the selected region
  d_sub <- d@xdata[d@xsubset,]
  head(d_sub)
#                Open     High      Low    Close
# 2007-03-28 48.33090 48.53595 48.33090 48.53595
# 2007-03-29 48.59236 48.69988 48.57432 48.69988
# 2007-03-30 48.74562 49.00218 48.74562 48.93546
# 2007-03-31 48.95616 49.09728 48.95616 48.97490
# 2007-04-01 48.94407 48.97816 48.80962 48.87032
# 2007-04-02 48.90488 49.08400 48.90488 49.06316
```

If this is something that's useful to you, you might want to add it to the `quantmod` sources, and recompile your own version of the package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's that worked perfectly. I'm new to R so I had no idea about the dump function, very useful.